# View.Bag retornando null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Estou criando um formulário em APS.NET CORE com C# e SQLServer de envio de e-mail e um dos campos é um dropdownlist que lista dados de uma tabela.

```
List<Templates> templates = new List<Templates>();
templates = _context.Templates.ToList();
ViewBag.languageTemplates = templates;
return View();
```

A lista "templates" é populada com os dados da tabela, mas a ViewBag retorna NULL na View. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda, estou aprendendo agora essa tecnologia.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei oq é o objeto context mas creio ser um database context, certo?

Se for vc precisa fazer uma query em cima dessa objeto para retornar a sua lista.

```
var templates = (from template in _context.Templates
                 select template).ToList()
```

O .ToList() no final vai materializar a sua query e retornar uma lista ao invés de um IQueryable. No entanto devo dizer que colocar essa lista na ViewBag não é o melhor aproach, tente colocar a lista na tua ViewModel e retornar a ViewModel dentro do seu return this.View();

Também não é recomendável fazer database queries dentro da tua controller, procure saber sobre o pattern UnitOfWork e Repository Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

achei o problema, não era nada de programação e nem estrutura não, estava passando um campo na construção do Dropdownlist com o nome do campo errado. O NULL que ele estava retornando era porque ele não tinha esse "atributo" no objeto. Obrigado @crawletas.